# How to use UndoRedo control (undoRedo features) in OpenLayers 2.13?

Tags: openlayers-2, undo-redo

I am using [UndoRedo](http://geometricnet.sourceforge.net/lib/UndoRedo.js) control in OpenLayers2.13, but this control do not work always and sometime an error :

`event.feature.layer is null` in `onDelete` function. Why does this error occur?

**UPDATE**

Definition undoRedo variable in JS:

```
 undoRedo=new UndoRedo(vectors);
```

call UndoRedo functions:

```
 <p:commandButton value="undo" onclick="undoRedo.undo()"/> 
 <p:commandButton value="redo" onclick="undoRedo.redo()"/>
```

Please help me.

Comment: Perhaps some reproducible code (is jsFiddle or similar) showing this behavior would help someone to diagnose it.

Comment: @JohnBarça I've updated the post.

Answer (score 1):

To find out what's causing the error you should inspect which features are given over to the delete function...for example with console.log:

```
DeleteFeature = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {
    initialize: function(layer, options) {
        OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(this, [options]);
        this.layer = layer;
        this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Feature(
            this, layer, {click: this.clickFeature}
        );
    },
    clickFeature: function(feature) {

console.log(feature);

// .......
}
```

For a working example you can check out:
http://rawgit.com/neogis-de/OpenLayers-Undo-Redo/master/examples/undo-redo.html

Perhaps you can check your insert/delete-workflows with this example and tell if the error occurs also in this example.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I found problem, I added features to layer with WKT reader, and when click on undo error occurs, that error is d is undefined in openlayers. d is same feature added with WKT that UndoRedo cant delete it.

Comment: You can help me to resolve this problem?

Comment: One error occurs in your example and that is: after rotation, resizing and dragging and then use `undo`, point handle remains on map. Please try it.

Comment: you could use mutually exclusive checkboxes to use only one modifyControl at a time and for the WKT-Feature you would have to adapt the UndoRedoControl to add the WKT-feature to the undo-stack

Comment: I think you do not understand my purpose, I mean, for example after using rotation, then use undo point handle remain on map. you can try your example.

Comment: it does not occur if you only tick one checkbox at a time...so if you use exclusive checkboxes the error does not occur